# Get attr color value based on current set theme

Tags: android, android-theme

In my activity I'm maintaining a `SuperActivity`, in which I'm setting the theme.

```
public class SuperActivity extends Activity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
    }
}
```

**themes.xml**

```
<!-- ImageBackround -->
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="ThemeLight">
    <item name="myBgColor">@color/translucent_black</item>
</style>
```

Now I want to fetch this color in one of my child activity.

As mentioned in this probable [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398610/how-to-get-the-attr-reference-in-code), I wrote:

```
int[] attrs = new int[] { R.attr.myBgColor /* index 0 */};
TypedArray ta = ChildActivity.this.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
int color = ta.getColor(0, android.R.color.background_light);
String c = getString(color);
ta.recycle();
```

But everytime I'm getting the value of the default value of `android.R.color.background_light` & not of `R.attr.myBgColor`.

Where I'm doing wrong. Am I passing the wrong context of `ChildActivity.this`?

Answer (score 12):

You have two possible solutions (one is what you actually have but I include both for the sake of completeness):

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
if (context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.xxx, typedValue, true))
  return typedValue.data;
else
  return Color.TRANSPARENT;
```

or

```
int[] attribute = new int[] { R.attr.xxx };
TypedArray array = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attribute);
int color = array.getColor(0, Color.TRANSPARENT);
array.recycle();
return color;
```

`Color.TRANSPARENT` could be any other default for sure. And yes, as you suspected, the context is **very** important. If you keep getting the default color instead of the real one, check out what context you are passing. It took me several hours to figure it out, I tried to spare some typing and simply used `getApplicationContext()` but it doesn't find the colors then...