# Is it possible to set colors for a Swipe Refresh Layout in XML?

Tags: android, xml, attr, swiperefreshlayout

I would like to set the theme-appropriate `ProgressBackgroundColorSchemeColor` and `colorSchemeColors` of my Swipe Refresh Layout in XML.
However, I can only seem to find solutions to do it programmatically [like this one below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320577/get-attr-color-value-based-on-current-set-theme/26348729#26348729).

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
int colorValue;
if (context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.xxx, typedValue, true))
  colorValue = typedValue.data;
else
  colorValue = Color.TRANSPARENT;

mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(colorValue);
```

These attributes are also not recognized in XML; so is it at all possible?

Answer (score -1):

The arrow appears in each color for every turn.

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(
  android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
  android.R.color.holo_green_light,
  android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
  android.R.color.holo_red_light
);
```

Comment: This like the solution I referenced, only sets the colors at run time rather than in the XML layout.
I added the `mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(colorValue)` to my question though because I didn't actually make clear what method I was using to set the colors.