# How to achieve ripple animation using support library?

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to add a ripple animation on button click. I did like below but it requires minSdKVersion to 21.

ripple.xml

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Button

```
<com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoButton
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple"
    android:text="@string/login_button" />
```

I want to make it backward compatible with the design library.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 405, accepted):

**Basic ripple setup**

- Ripples contained within the view.
  `android:background="?selectableItemBackground"`
- Ripples that extend beyond the view's bounds:
  `android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

  Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9409391/2308514) for resolving `?(attr)` xml references in Java code.

**Support Library**

- Using `?attr:` (or the `?` shorthand) instead of `?android:attr` references the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7), so is available back to API 7.

**Ripples with images/backgrounds**

- To have a image or background and overlaying ripple the easiest solution is to wrap the `View` in a `FrameLayout` with the ripple set with `setForeground()` or `setBackground()`.

Honestly there is no clean way of doing this otherwise.

Comment: This does not add ripple support to versions prior to 21.

Comment: It may not add ripple support but this solution degrades nicely. This actually solved the particular issue that I was having. I wanted a ripple effect on L and a simple select on prior version of android.

Comment: @AndroidDev, @Dave Jensen: Actually, using the `?attr:` instead of `?android:attr` references the v7 support library, which, assuming you use it, gives you backwards compatibility to API 7. See: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7

Comment: @BenDLH but android studio says that the attribute is marked as private in the design support package. Any solution for this?

Comment: What if I also want to have background color?

Comment: Like the above comment, can you do this over a existing background, I have seen other apps with this.

Comment: @john carter @stanley santoso The easiest way is to wrap the `View` in a `FrameLayout` and set it with `setForeground()` or `setBackground()`. Honestly there is no clean way of doing this otherwise, though Nick Butcher did post [this](https://plus.google.com/+NickButcher/posts/azEU6s4APbu) on the subject.

Comment: Ripple effect is NOT meant to be for API < 21. The Ripple is a click effect  of material design. Google Design Team perspective is not show it on pre-lollipop devices. pre-lolipop have their own click effects (defaults to light-blue cover). The offered answer suggests to use the default click-effect of the system. If you want to customize the colors of the click effect, you need to make a drawable and place it at res/drawable-v21 for the ripple click-effect (with the <ripple> drawable), and at res/drawable for non-ripple click effect (with <selector> drawable usually)

Comment: Thanks! I searched a LOT for that. any ideas on how to change the ripple color?

Comment: The correct syntax for using the support library is `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`.

Comment: Any idea how I can set this for the whole application in `res/values/styles.xml`?

Comment: @stanleysantoso You can use android:foreground instead of android:background

Answer (score 59):

I formerly voted to close this question as off-topic but actually I changed my mind as this is quite nice visual effect which, unfortunately, is not yet part of support library. It will most likely  show up in future update, but there's no time frame announced.

Luckily there are few custom implementations already available:

- https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect
- https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple
- https://github.com/siriscac/RippleView
- https://github.com/ozodrukh/RippleDrawable

including Materlial themed widget sets compatible with older versions of Android:

- https://github.com/keithellis/MaterialWidget

so you can try one of these or google for other "material widgets" or so...

Comment: This is now part of the support library, see my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I used the [second lib](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple), the first was too slow in slow phones.

Answer (score 28):

I made a simple class that makes ripple buttons, i never needed it in the end so its not the best, But here it is:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Button;

public class RippleView extends Button
{
    private float duration = 250;

    private float speed = 1;
    private float radius = 0;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private float endRadius = 0;
    private float rippleX = 0;
    private float rippleY = 0;
    private int width = 0;
    private int height = 0;
    private OnClickListener clickListener = null;
    private Handler handler;
    private int touchAction;
    private RippleView thisRippleView = this;

    public RippleView(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public RippleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RippleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        if (isInEditMode())
            return;

        handler = new Handler();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if(radius > 0 && radius < endRadius)
        {
            canvas.drawCircle(rippleX, rippleY, radius, paint);
            if(touchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event)
    {
        rippleX = event.getX();
        rippleY = event.getY();

        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                touchAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_UP;

                radius = 1;
                endRadius = Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(width - rippleX, rippleX), rippleY), height - rippleY);
                speed = endRadius / duration * 10;
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        if(radius < endRadius)
                        {
                            radius += speed;
                            paint.setAlpha(90 - (int) (radius / endRadius * 90));
                            handler.postDelayed(this, 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            clickListener.onClick(thisRippleView);
                        }
                    }
                }, 10);
                invalidate();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            {
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                touchAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL;
                radius = 0;
                invalidate();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                touchAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_UP;
                endRadius = Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(width - rippleX, rippleX), rippleY), height - rippleY);
                paint.setAlpha(90);
                radius = endRadius/4;
                invalidate();
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                if(rippleX < 0 || rippleX > width || rippleY < 0 || rippleY > height)
                {
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    touchAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL;
                    radius = 0;
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    touchAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
                    invalidate();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l)
    {
        clickListener = l;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Since many people are looking for something like this i made a class that can make other views have the ripple effect:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class RippleViewCreator extends FrameLayout
{
    private float duration = 150;
    private int frameRate = 15;

    private float speed = 1;
    private float radius = 0;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private float endRadius = 0;
    private float rippleX = 0;
    private float rippleY = 0;
    private int width = 0;
    private int height = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private int touchAction;

    public RippleViewCreator(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public RippleViewCreator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RippleViewCreator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        if (isInEditMode())
            return;

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.control_highlight_color));
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        setWillNotDraw(true);
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        setClickable(true);
    }

    public static void addRippleToView(View v)
    {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)v.getParent();
        int index = -1;
        if(parent != null)
        {
            index = parent.indexOfChild(v);
            parent.removeView(v);
        }
        RippleViewCreator rippleViewCreator = new RippleViewCreator(v.getContext());
        rippleViewCreator.setLayoutParams(v.getLayoutParams());
        if(index == -1)
            parent.addView(rippleViewCreator, index);
        else
            parent.addView(rippleViewCreator);
        rippleViewCreator.addView(v);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

        if(radius > 0 && radius < endRadius)
        {
            canvas.drawCircle(rippleX, rippleY, radius, paint);
            if(touchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event)
    {
        rippleX = event.getX();
        rippleY = event.getY();

        touchAction = event.getAction();
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

                radius = 1;
                endRadius = Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(width - rippleX, rippleX), rippleY), height - rippleY);
                speed = endRadius / duration * frameRate;
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        if(radius < endRadius)
                        {
                            radius += speed;
                            paint.setAlpha(90 - (int) (radius / endRadius * 90));
                            handler.postDelayed(this, frameRate);
                        }
                        else if(getChildAt(0) != null)
                        {
                            getChildAt(0).performClick();
                        }
                    }
                }, frameRate);
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            {
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                endRadius = Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(width - rippleX, rippleX), rippleY), height - rippleY);
                paint.setAlpha(90);
                radius = endRadius/3;
                invalidate();
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                if(rippleX < 0 || rippleX > width || rippleY < 0 || rippleY > height)
                {
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    touchAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    invalidate();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        invalidate();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public final void addView(@NonNull View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)
    {
        //limit one view
        if (getChildCount() > 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException(this.getClass().toString()+" can only have one child.");
        }
        super.addView(child, index, params);
    }
}
```

Comment: else if (clickListener != null) {
                            clickListener.onClick(thisRippleView);
                        }

Comment: Simple to implement... plug & play :)

Comment: I am getting ClassCastException if I use this class over each view of a RecyclerView.

Comment: @Ali_Waris The support library can deal with ripples these days but to fix this all you have to do is, instead of using `addRippleToView` to add the ripple effect. Rather make each view in the `RecyclerView` a `RippleViewCreator`

Answer (score 24):

Sometimes you have a custom background, in that cases a better solution is use `android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"`

### Update

If you want ripple effect with rounded corners and custom background you can use this:

background_ripple.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="@color/ripple_color">
<item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

layout.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_play"
    android:background="@drawable/background_ripple"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/play_now" />
```

I used this on API >= 21

Comment: Yes, but it works on API >= 23 or on devices with 21 API, but only in CardView or FrameLayout

Comment: If your custom background have round corners, the ripple effect will look ugly.

Comment: in case if someone needs the ripple color
<color name="ripple_color">#1f000000</color>`

Answer (score 24):

It's very simple ;-)

First you must create two drawable file one for old api version and another one for newest version, Of course! if you create the drawable file for newest api version android studio suggest you to create old one automatically. and finally set this drawable to your background view.

**Sample drawable for new api version (res/drawable-v21/ripple.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/round_corner" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

**Sample drawable for old api version (res/drawable/ripple.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/round_corner" />
</shape>
```

For more info about ripple drawable just visit this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html

Comment: It's really very simple!

Comment: This solution should be definitely much more upvoted! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

sometimes will b usable this line on any layout or components.

```
 android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Like as.

```
 <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_ticket_checkin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
```