# How to create ripple effect in simple layout

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, rippledrawable

How can I have a ripple effect in a simple linear/relative layout when touching the layout?

I've tried setting the background of a layout to something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight" >

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>

</ripple>
```

However I'm only seeing a plain white background and no ripple effect when touching the layout.  What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

For reference, here is my layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:clickable="true">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The view hosting the ripple needs to be enabled and clickable or focusable.

Comment: Thanks Alanv, see below for my response.  Basically I am marking my layout I want to have the ripple effect in as clickable, but it does not work still.

Comment: Also, this works fine if I remove the `<item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>` section.  So I'm not sure how this is supposed to work if I wanted a background color on the layout.  Laying this on top of another layout with a background color also does not work!

Comment: What color is the ripple being drawn in your view, e.g. what color does colorControlHighlight resolve to?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It turns out this is working as intended.  The standard Material theme colorControlHighlight value is `#40ffffff`.  So on a white background, this will not show up.  Changing the highlight color to something else works, and/or changing the background color of the object.

Thanks all (especially Alanv for pointing me in the right direction).

Comment: if I'm using android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" on my view how can I change the background of the object?

Comment: Nevermind I found that the selectableItemBackground default state is transparent. So, I set a view under it with the color I wanted.

Comment: quick note: you can change `colorControlHighlight` in your `styles.xml`. Add it to your custom theme for instance.

Answer (score 328):

Set these properties on your layout (if your layout has the default white/light background):

```
          android:clickable="true"
          android:focusable="true"
          android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

*You don't need a custom drawable in this case.*

However, if your layout has a black/dark background, you'd have to create your own ripple drawable like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- An white rectangle ripple. -->
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/white">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

And then set this ripple drawable as your **android:background** property.

You can see many examples of these types of ripples in AOSP: [in here](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/search?q=ripple&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&project=art&project=bionic&project=bootable&project=build&project=cts&project=dalvik&project=developers&project=development&project=device&project=docs&project=external&project=frameworks&project=hardware&project=kernel&project=libcore&project=libnativehelper&project=packages&project=pdk&project=platform_testing&project=prebuilts&project=sdk&project=system&project=test&project=toolchain&project=tools)

Comment: what if i have to give different color as background ? Then what should be the best approach ?

Comment: @AnujSharma Have you tried giving color resource for `background`?

Comment: yes i tried that, in case i need to add ripple xml in drawable folder, i thought i can use this single line to generate ripple effect

Comment: @ralphspoon See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604134/how-to-achieve-ripple-animation-using-support-library

Comment: @AnujSharma you can create a drawable with color and ripple efect and give it as a background to your layout.

Comment: If you'd like another background color you can set that color as background and put "?attr/selectableItemBackground" as android:foreground instead

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky now the error has gone but no ripple. nothing happens when  I click

Comment: Keep in mind you also have the option to use android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"    With it being border less The ripple effect will extend out to the parent view. This may look better in many cases.

Comment: Beware that the `foreground` attribute has been added in API 23 (Android 6.0) and `has no effect on API levels lower than 23` (as per Android Studio warning)

Comment: @flawyte Correct, however the `foreground` attribute is available on a `FrameLayout` below API v23, I think down to v16.

Comment: @MattMc I believe it's been available on `FrameLayout` since API 1, however there's a [better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61202414/1276306) than wrapping your `ImageView` in an additional container just to add a ripple.

Answer (score 70):

I'm adding this in addition to [Igor Ganapolsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238937/igor-ganapolsky)'s answer in case anyone wants to have a layout with different color and also have a ripple effect. You simply create a ripple effect in drawables like this:

> ripple.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/rippleColor"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop"> <!-- ripple effect color -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/backgroundColor" /> <!-- background color -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

then give it as your layout's background or any button as [Igor Ganapolsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238937/igor-ganapolsky) mentioned in his answer.

```
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@drawable/ripple"
```

Answer (score 52):

You have to alter following code snippet in any widget(`TextView`/`Button`) and you can implement **Ripple Effect**:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: hmm foreground? this is great!

Comment: This is helpful if you already have a android:background="@color/colorAccent" set

Comment: @aero It is helpful, even if you don't set any background.

Comment: this works on layouts and custom views in addition to widgets.

Comment: Keep in mind you also have the option to use android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"    With it being border less The ripple effect will extend out to the parent view. This may look better in many cases.

Comment: @MichaelKern Yes, you're right, also it is based upon everybody's requirement in their code.

Comment: Beware that the `foreground` attribute has been added in API 23 (Android 6.0) and `has no effect on API levels lower than 23` (as per Android Studio warning)

Comment: @flawyte Correct, however the foreground attribute is available on a FrameLayout below API v23, I think down to v16.

Comment: @MattMc I believe it's been available on `FrameLayout` since API 1, however there's a [better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61202414/1276306) than wrapping your `ImageView` in an additional container just to add a ripple.

Answer (score 15):

This is an example for clicking on a sample layout with ripple effect :

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: That's simple awesome how simple this is and the simple fact that this simply Just Works™.

Answer (score 9):

Set `android:clickable="true"` on your layout.

Answer (score 6):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#cfd8dc"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#d1c4e9" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Use this **ripple.xml in Drawable folder**, then assign it as  View's

**android:background="@drawable/ripple"**

**android:clickable="true"**

Answer (score 2):

Simply add default ripple effect with `android:background="?selectableItemBackground"`

**Like:**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            >

           ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this into your layout:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Note: There is a bug in API documentation. It will work only on **API >= 23**

For **all API** **levels** use this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38984185/6897909)

Comment: Your link redirect this same page

Comment: Keep in mind you also have the option to use android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"    With it being border less The ripple effect will extend out to the parent view. This may look better in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

I tries all those answers and nothing worked to me, so, I solved creating the following style:

```
<style name="Button.Borderless" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">-6dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">-6dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">6dp</item>
</style>
```

And then, I applied to my linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/ll_my_ripple"
      style="@style/Button.Borderless">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a circlar effect use the below code:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```