# TextView setting attr/selectableItemBackground in drawable

Tags: android, textview

Current my textview already has a background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@color/frageventButtonColor" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

How can I also add the

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

to it as well, making it clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:background="?actionBarItemBackground"
```

gives the circular ripple on api 23+ and defaults to

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

the square ripple

if not api 23

Answer (score 1):

If you have minSdk 23, use `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`

If not, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32913619/6623972)

Comment: Ripple also requires min 21 api except mines is currently 19