# How to put ripple effect on relative layout in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have created my custom button for my card-view in android using Relative Layout and calling that button via <include layout functionality. Everything is working fine I just want to know put ripple effect on that click how to do that?

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/questa"
            android:text="Know More"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff">
        </TextView>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Include Layout Code:

```
<include
                android:id="@+id/btnViewDetails"
                style="@style/CardView.Button"
                layout="@layout/button"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewDivider"
                />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create ripple effect in simple layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006288/how-to-create-ripple-effect-in-simple-layout)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to achieve ripple animation using support library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604134/how-to-achieve-ripple-animation-using-support-library)

Answer (score 2):

you just add 3 line code in RelativeLayout

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 1):

I just use 1 line

```
android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `ripple` to your **background** parent.

suppose that you have a `ripple` file like this, file name is `ripple` in `drawable` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#9D9D9D">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#9D9D9D" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_all_rows" />
</ripple>
```

*** The **first** `item` add effect to your `component` or `button` and the **second** `item` is state that you **didnt** click on `button`.

`drawable_all_rows` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />

</shape>
```

Then you add this to your `relative layout` **background** like this :

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/_4sdp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:endColor="@color/blue"
            android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:type="linear" />
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/_4sdp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```