# Android Ripple effect to Listview items

Tags: android, listview, rippledrawable

Is there a way to add ripple effect to Listview items in the android support library since ripple tag only works with API level 21+.

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604134/how-to-achieve-ripple-animation-using-support-library-in-android

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot add ripple effect to ListView items using android support library since the support library only supports Lollipop features like `FAB, SnackBar, AppBarLayout, FloatingEditText, CoordinatorLayout, CollapsingToolbarLayout, TabLayout, NavigationView`. If you need to create custom ripple effect for listitem in ListView follow this [tutorial](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2014/11/ripple-effect-for-android-textview-and.html). It has a very good sample creating RippleEffect by extending RelativeLayout, so that you can assign this view as a parent layout in a listitem.