# Ripple effect on ListView item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am new to Android development. I am trying to develop a SMS app for Android. I am successful with reading the inbox and contacts and display them in a `ListView` item. Now, what I want to achieve is to have a ripple effect on these `ListView` items every-time they are clicked or touched or selected. I used **listSelector** but seems it's not working. If anybody could help me, below is my code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/msglist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
        android:listSelector="#777777" />
```

Comment: try search RippleDrawable which available since api level 21, and try to make it available on your desire platform.

Comment: @VinceStyling  have tried RippleDrawable but still it doesn't work. Take note that I am using a custom theme for my activity. If I use AppThemes ripple effect works, but when I apply a custom theme there's no ripple effect anymore.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/26604471/2414129

Answer (score 21):

You are going to inflate a layout in your `Adapter` for `ListView`, right? Then you can go to that layout.xml and set the background of the root element to:

```xml
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

**NOTICE:** Ripple effect can only happen above API 21(Lollipop) by doing this. Under Lollipop, when you touch the item, a transparent blue layer will appear and overlay your source content, which is shown as selecting state.

Comment: If your root element is `FrameLayout` or subclass of it such as `CardView`, you can set `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` instead. As a result, you can set color of it easily by setting background.

Answer (score 2):

For enabling the ripple effect for list items via the XML layout, the following attributes need to be set in the root layout:

```xml
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

With only the `android:backgroudn` attribute the ripple effect might not show up on click.

More information can be found in [Customize Touch Feedback](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations#Touch) (page contains deprecation warning for the other options).