# Android: animation on layout after button clicked for minimum SDK version of 14

Tags: android, animation, slidetoggle

How can I do exactly the same effect as this in Android in minimum SDK version 14 application?

[image]

- Background effect
- slide toggle button
- my minSDKVersion is 14

Is looks like a circle enlarging animation on background, or is there a more specific function for it?

many thanks...

Comment: Do not redirect if you have image as example. :) Post in question only.

Comment: Thanks for remind I never notice I can do that ""

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look [Circular Reveal from touch point](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations#circular-reveal-from-touch-point):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.square_yellow) {
            revealFromCoordinates(motionEvent.getRawX(), motionEvent.getRawY());
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private Animator animateRevealColorFromCoordinates(int x, int y) {
    float finalRadius = (float) Math.hypot(viewRoot.getWidth(), viewRoot.getHeight());

    Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(viewRoot, x, y, 0, finalRadius);
    viewRoot.setBackgroundColor(color);
    anim.start();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have concrete examples for exactly what you display in your example, however here are some examples that you can use to get close:

You can use a simple ToggleButton for the switch. See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

For the ripple animation, take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26604471/1738090 There are several examples there which display a "ripple" effect. You could easily reuse this animation, decrease the opacity and set the animation to the background of the bigger views as shown in your example.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this library [Material Animation library](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations) for implementing background reveal animation and [Toggle Button library](https://github.com/zcweng/ToggleButton) for checkbox animations.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that is interested, I went ahead and created a demo app to demonstrate this effect using circular reveal from two switches. You can download it here. It's API 21 and above however.

https://github.com/o4wcoder/CircularRevealDemo