# Android- Can we create material views programmatically?

Tags: android

Is it possible to create Material Design views (like button, textView, ...) programmatically?
like

```
    AwesomeButton btnTest=new AwesomeButton (context);
```

i want full featured library like [rey5137](https://github.com/rey5137/material) but without XML usage and support old android(maybe Android 2.3 and up).

Comment: I found answer in "Nicolas Tyler"  post  from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604134/how-to-achieve-ripple-animation-using-support-library) page.

Answer (score 0):

material design is all about different combinations of items in xml. you cannot design without xml. it is not java swing don't forget, whatever you want to design their base should be on drawable or layout folder, not on java code

**update for the edited question**

in your example, you say AwesomeButton, in order to have something like this, you need to have a library, which also has xml design file including all those fancy visual effects. If you don't design how are you supposed to create a pre-designed button.

chamran, you are making it complicated my friend, you can't design a button via code, you have to have a xml file for your own custom materials. Even the default button has a xml.

Comment: can i inflate drawable in code? how can i use drawable to create material ( button for example) ?

Comment: you can inflate an xml to a view, and that's done via getView method for example. But again, can't do anything without having xml. that's the answer