# Adding ripple effect on android project

Tags: android, ripple, rippledrawable

Is there any library or dependency to add ripple effect in existing project,I *don't* want define ripple effect on each views, just want to add effect on one place for whole project.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604134/how-to-achieve-ripple-animation-using-support-library) out

Comment: i don't want to add ripple effect on each button specifically, i just want to add as we are adding theme of the app.

Comment: i know but you can have it in your style or theme as well. the code is added to xml. it is `android:background = ...`

Comment: use styles pattern

Answer (score 0):

Ripple effect is for API 21 and above. You can define in app theme as follows:

Without **AppCompat**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/your_custom_color</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

**your_custom_color** will appear on `Button`, `ImageButton`, etc.`Views`

With **AppCompat**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/your_custom_color</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Also, Using `?android:colorControlHighlight`, `?attr/selectableItemBackground` will give the ripple the same color as the built-in ripples in your app for any `View` as `background`.