# App crashing with error 'Unfortunately, Calculator has stopped' in Android KitKat 4.4.4 version mobile

Tags: android, android-resources

I am running my Calculator app from Android studio in KitKat 4.4.4 version mobile and I get the error 'Unfortunately, Calculator has stopped'. Below is the error got from Logcat from Android Studio:

```
03-03 10:18:14.279 3583-3583/com.saashtechs.saashcalculator E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.util.Locale$Builder', referenced from method com.android.calculator2.CalculatorNumericPadLayout.onFinishInflate
03-03 10:18:14.319 3583-3583/com.saashtechs.saashcalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.saashtechs.saashcalculator, PID: 3583
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.saashtechs.saashcalculator/com.android.calculator2.CalculatorGB}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class Button
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1096)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class Button
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:720)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                  at com.android.calculator2.Calculator.onCreate(Calculator.java:149)
                                                                                  at com.android.calculator2.CalculatorGB.onCreate(CalculatorGB.java:27)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1096) 
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/pad_button_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f060060
                                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3453)
                                                                                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:614)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3585)
                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:698)
                                                                                  at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:66)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:62)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                  at com.android.calculator2.Calculator.onCreate(Calculator.java:149) 
                                                                                  at com.android.calculator2.CalculatorGB.onCreate(CalculatorGB.java:27) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1096) 
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                               Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #18: invalid drawable tag ripple
                                                                                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:969)
                                                                                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:913)
                                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3449)
                                                                                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:614) 
                                                                                  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3585) 
                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:698) 
                                                                                  at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:66) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:62) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                  at com.android.calculator2.Calculator.onCreate(Calculator.java:149) 
                                                                                  at com.android.calculator2.CalculatorGB.onCreate(CalculatorGB.java:27) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1096) 
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone please help why I getting this error?

Also, please let me know which are the files I need to show here so that you guys can fix this error

Below is the 'build.gradle' file code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.android.application"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sg.calculator"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile "AndroidManifest.xml"
            java.srcDirs = ["src"]
            res.srcDirs = ["res"]
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
    compile files('exp4j-0.4.8.jar')
    compile files('nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
}
```

XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/display"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/display_background_color"
    android:elevation="4dip">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/tb"
        android:theme="@style/CalculatorTheme"
        android:title=""
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RAD"
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/rad"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:onClick="onButtonClick"
            android:theme="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:minWidth="5dp"
            android:minHeight="5dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.android.calculator2.CalculatorEditText
        android:id="@+id/formula"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tb"
        style="@style/DisplayEditTextStyle.Formula"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:textColor="@color/display_formula_text_color" />

    <com.android.calculator2.CalculatorEditText
        android:id="@+id/result"
        style="@style/DisplayEditTextStyle.Result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/formula"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="@color/display_result_text_color" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

'res/drawable/pad_button_background.xml' file code:

```
<ripple xmlns:
android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/pad_button_ripple_color" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add your XML file.

Comment: @Heisen-Berg, which XML file sir? AndroidManifest.xml file ?

Comment: Nope. You have to learn through your error what is it about and where are occuring. Clearly from your logcat you are getting error in your layout XML file. So, add your layout XML file which is used in CalculatorGB activity.

Comment: @Heisen-Berg, added sir

Comment: Where are you using `pad_button_background.xml` in your project ?.

Comment: Inside drawable folder. Added pad_button_background.xml code also

Comment: **which** res/values folder did you put that file in?

Comment: pad_button_background.xml is in res/drawable folder

Comment: `Binary XML file line #18: invalid drawable tag ripple`... Are you sure KitKat supports `<ripple>` drawables? You need a different drawable for different API levels

Comment: Is there any common drawables which supports all API levels?

Comment: Yes, but Ripples were only added at API Level 21

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class Button check this error this is main reason why your app is crashing

Answer (score 0):

> RippleDrawable - added in API level 21

So you need to move that XML file to at least a `res/drawable-v21` folder. (Make if not exists)

Also see - [How to achieve ripple animation using support library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604134/how-to-achieve-ripple-animation-using-support-library)

Comment: But how to fix that for other API levels sir ?

Comment: Add any other possible drawable named `pad_button_background.xml` into `res/drawable`