# Achieve toolbar menu item click ripple effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-drawable, rippledrawable

I try to use `padding` to increase the touch area of a button. I use

```
<ImageButton
    android:paddingRight="32dp"
    android:paddingEnd="32dp"
    android:id="@+id/confirm_image_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:src="?attr/confirmIcon" />
```

The click area is enlarge. But, `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` click effect no longer shown as a perfect circle.

[image]

---

I try to use `duplicateParentState` technique to overcome.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingRight="32dp"
    android:paddingEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    <ImageButton
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:id="@+id/confirm_image_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:src="?attr/confirmIcon" />
</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Now,

1. The clicked area is enlarged.
2. The `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` circle effect is a perfect circle.

However, it seems to have some weird behavior. When I click on the actual area of the `ImageButton`, the circle press effect is not shown.

[image]

**May I know why it is so, and how can I overcome it? I tested using API 26.**

Note, I try to avoid using `TouchDelegate` technique, unless I'm forced to, as it makes our code more complicated.

---

### Additional information

The following is the correct behavior, exhibited by the button for `Toolbar`.

**Ripple effect is shown when the click region is outside the button**

[image]

**Ripple effect is shown when the click region is within the button**

[image]

However, I have no idea how they implement such behavior.

Comment: I would suggest writing your animation and click behavior. I think this is the fastest solution.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

After spending some time I finally found how the *"toolbar mystery"* works. It's `ActionMenuItemView`, that is being displayed on the toolbar. And you can see, that inside [xml file](https://github.com/socialize/android-appcompat/blob/master/res/layout/abc_action_menu_item_layout.xml#L30) it has `style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"` applied to it. `?attr/actionButtonStyle` corresponds to [`Widget.Material.ActionButton`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/styles_material.xml#945) and within this style we can see `<item name="background">?attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>`.

If you want to apply the same effect to your `ImageButton`, then all you have to do is to apply `android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"` to it. Thus, having following xml layout:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/confirm_image_button"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_check_black_24dp" />
```

You'll receive this output:

[image]

<sup>*Turned on "Show layout bounds" so that actual bounds of `ImageButton` are visible*</sup>

If you are curious what `?attr/actionBarItemBackground` actually represents, [here's it](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/action_bar_item_background_material.xml#L17):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight"
    android:radius="20dp" />
```

Thus, you can create your drawable and apply it as a background to `ImageButton`.

Comment: Thank you. That's was the answer I'm looking for, without all sort of workaround to achieve such purpose.

Comment: Amazing answer, been looking for it for a long time. Bounty well deserved!

Answer (score 2):

> The ripples on Android 5.0 start in the center of each view. According
>   to the Material Design rules, the ripples should start where the touch
>   event occurs, so they seem to flow outward from the finger. **This was
>   addressed in Android 5.1, but was a bug in Android 5.0**
>
> To fix this, you need to use the `setHotspot()` method, added to
>   Drawable in API Level 21. `setHotspot()` provides to the drawable a
>   **“hot spot”**, and `RippleDrawable` apparently uses this as the emanation point for the ripple effect. `setHotspot()` takes a pair of
>   float values, presumably with an eye towards using `setHotspot()`
>   inside of an `OnTouchListener`, as the `MotionEvent` reports `X/Y`
>   positions of the touch event with float values.

Thanks to The Busy Coder's Guide book

You can use this code to correct the ripples bug:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
       btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
          @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
          @Override
          public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
              v.getBackground()
                .setHotspot(event.getX(), event.getY());
              return(false);
          }
     });
}
```

other solution:

[How to achieve ripple animation using support library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604134/how-to-achieve-ripple-animation-using-support-library)

[RippleDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable)

---

another solution:

**in your first try:**

> I try to use padding to increase the touch area of a button.

**you can use this code to put center of ripple at center of `ImageButton`**:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
           btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
              @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
              @Override
              public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                  v.getBackground()
                    .setHotspot(v.getWidth()/2f, v.getHeight()/2f);//setting hot spot at center of ImageButton
                  return(false);
              }
         });
    }
```

---

maybe another solution when `FrameLayout` wraps `ImageButton`:

as you say:

> However, it seems to have some weird behavior. When I click on the
>   actual area of the ImageButton, the circle press effect is not shown.

a work around for this problem may be to add `frameLayout.performClick()` in the `onClick()` method of `ImageButton`

or you can simulate a touch on `frameLayout` like this code when `ImageButton` is clicked:

```
// Obtain MotionEvent object
long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
float x = 0.0f;// or x = frameLayout.getWidth()/2f
float y = 0.0f;// or y = frameLayout.getHeight()/2f
// List of meta states found here: developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()
int metaState = 0;
MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
    downTime, 
    eventTime, 
    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 
    x, 
    y, 
    metaState
);

// Dispatch touch event to view
frameLayout.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
```

Comment: May I know the reason it doesn't work without this workaround?

Comment: Do you have some reference source regarding this bug?

Comment: I'm tested using API 26. I can confirm your proposed solution doesn't work. `OnTouchListener` is triggered, but the circle press effect is not shown.

Comment: I had read through those answer but it doesn't answer my doubt. I know how to achieve ripple effect. (As you can see my ripple effect is achieved using technique from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28715666/72437 ) But my problem is different, which is stated in my question clearly.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng at your first try which only has ImageButton with padding you can use `v.getBackground().setHotspot(v.getWidth()/2f, v.getHeight()/2f);` to position center of ripple at center of image button. see my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your problem lies in that you have an `ImageButton` and not just an `ImageView`. The default style for the `ImageButton` is:

```
<style name="Widget.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default</item>
</style>
```

Replaced was the background, but you still left the item clickable and focusable. In your example, the real active item is the container, so you can either use a regular `ImageView`, or set the item to be not clickable and focusable manually. Also it is important to set the click listener on the container, *not* the button/image itself, because it will become clickable.

This is one variant:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingEnd="48dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_check_black_24dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

The other one is the same, except the view inside the `FrameLayout` is:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_check_black_24dp"
    />
```

Here's the visual proof:

[image: screen capture]

This was captured on an emulator running Android 5.0.2. I tried this on my 8.0 phone, works as well.

Comment: I try to replace `ImageButton` with `ImageView`. It still exhibit the same problematic behavior as I described from `ImageButton`. It the pressed region is on the `ImageView`, circle press effect is not shown.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng What about setting focusable and clickable to `false` manually? Also, did you set the `onClickListener` on the image or on the container?

Comment: Yes and yes. I tried https://gist.github.com/yccheok/1657ad18cc5084eb37f7a667ddb3a4b7 , and try to `onClickListener` on container and/or button. (various combinations). It doesn't work. Have you tried on your side? Does it work for you?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng Perfectly. I've updated my answer with the actual code. Maybe something is wrong with your device?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `android:duplicateParentState="true"`, simply set `android:clickable="false"` to your `ImageButton` will make your `Button` highlight when click on it and its parent

```
<ImageButton
       ...
       android:duplicateParentState="true"
       android:clickable="false"
  />
```

#### Explanation

From the [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setduplicateparentstateenabled)

> When duplication is enabled, this view gets its drawable state from its parent rather than from its own internal properties

=> View change state base on parent state. 
The default `clickable` of `ImageButton` is true => when you click at `ImageButton`, the state of is parent not change => `ImageButton` not highlight

=> Set `clickable=false` will solve the problem

#### SOME NOTE

1) Don't forget set `clickable=true` on its parent
2) For `TextView`, `ImageView` (or some view which have clickable=false as default), you don't need to set `clickable=false`
3) **BE careful** when use `setOnClickListener`

```
public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable OnClickListener l) {
    if (!isClickable()) {
        setClickable(true);
    }
    getListenerInfo().mOnClickListener = l;
}
```

When use `setOnClickListener` it will also `setClickable(true)` so in this case you **must only** set the `setOnClickListener` for its parent layout

Comment: Have you tried out the solution by yourself? As, I had tried it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng of course, it will work. I am using this way many times