# Transitive effect perform on button click in android programmatically?

Tags: java, android

When user click in the app, i need to show ripple effect on button after click perform but i need to apply this programmatically.

Comment: If you're just asking how to do a ripple effect, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604134/how-to-achieve-ripple-animation-using-support-library

Comment: Did you take a look to this article? https://medium.com/@sajidhzazahir/android-ripple-effect-with-background-drawable-programmatically-1128d92a21b3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
    yourBtn = findViewById(R.id.your_btn);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, outValue, true);
        yourBtn.setForeground(getResources().getDrawable(outValue.resourceId, null));
    }
```

If you didn't set a specific background for your button, then you also use this code snippet:

```
    startSearchBtn = findViewById(R.id.start_search_btn);
    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, outValue, true);
    startSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
```