# RecyclerView ?android:attr/selectableItemBackground does not work on items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have this items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/colorPreview" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/colorName" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I use it separately, the selectableItemBackground animates when I click the view. But when I use it for the items in a RecyclerView, the effect on click does not happen anymore. How can I fix this?

PS: this is the listener on the RecyclerView, if it is relevant:

```
 public ColorListOnItemTouchListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener clickListener) {
    mClickListener = clickListener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                if(childView != null && mClickListener != null) {
                    mClickListener.onItemLongPress(childView, index);
                }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            if(childView != null && mClickListener != null) {
                mClickListener.onItemClick(childView, index);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you!

Edit:

```
 public class ColorsCursorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ColorsCursorAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int layout = R.layout.color_item;
    private Cursor mCursor;

    public ColorsCursorAdapter(Cursor c) {
        super();
        this.mCursor = c;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout, parent, false);
        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.colorName);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.colorPreview);
        return new ViewHolder(v, name, image);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        int color = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ColorItem.COLUMN_COLOR));
        holder.colorName.setText(Utils.getColorString(color));
        holder.colorPreview.setImageDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(mCursor != null) {
            return mCursor.getCount();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void swapCursor(Cursor c) {
        mCursor = c;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public Cursor getCursor() {
        return mCursor;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView colorName;
        public ImageView colorPreview;

        public ViewHolder(View root, TextView colorName, ImageView colorPreview) {
            super(root);
            root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //
                }
            });
            this.colorName = colorName;
            this.colorPreview = colorPreview;
        }
    }
}
```

And the adapter is created with:

```
colorList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new ColorsCursorAdapter(null);
    colorList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Did you tried setting onClick listener on holderView in adapter?

Comment: I did... and it did not work

Comment: but did you set listener on a view which has selectablebackground set?

Comment: It works fine for me (see [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/CardRippleList2)).

Comment: @Hellboy yes, i was setting the listener on the root element of the item which has the background (RelativeLayout)

Comment: post code how you create your recycler and adapter

Comment: added some more code

Comment: Another thing. Replace "?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" with "?attr/selectableItemBackground"

Comment: tried it ... still no luck

Comment: I am stuck with the same issue. It works even in other adapters, but not on a particular one. Can't figure out what causes this. If I manage to solve it somehow, will notify you :)

Answer (score 54):

Something that was not mentioned in other answers: setting `android:clickable="true"` is required in order to make the animations work when there is no OnClickListener attached to the view.

Comment: I wish I could upvote twice, cause this answered apparently helped me long time ago

Answer (score 24):

Instead of setting it as background, I set it as foreground, it works. Hope it would helpful.

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: I don't think it's going to work on API below 23 though.

Comment: @VarvaraKalinina is there a way to make it work for api levels below 23 ?

Answer (score 10):

In your items.xml, set FrameLayout as the root layout and set selectableItemBackground for FrameLayout. It works for me, but I do not know why.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!-- your code -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The reason for this is, that FrameLayout supports the `foreground` attribute on lower API levels than 23. Other views just support it starting API level 23.

Comment: Using this in combination with `android:clickable="true"` worked for me

Comment: @Aba when I set clickable to true, I don't receive my OnClickListener events.

Answer (score 2):

View that you want to have ripple effect has to be clickable. You can either do that by specifying android:clickable="true" in XML file or setting onClickListener programmatically. When you are using this on item inside RecyclerView and you are using Kotlin set onClickListener on "itemView" from ViewHolder class.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same behavior. On my side it was related to the fact that when I clicked a list item within a fragment and directly replacing that fragment with another, the animation hadn't no time to be shown. As soon as I removed the fragment replacement, I could see the animation.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        if(childView != null && mClickListener != null) {
            mClickListener.onItemClick(childView, index);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Return false might fix this issue. For me, I was overriding onTouch on my button and returning true at the end. Returning false enabled the touch animation to happen from setting:

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was caused by `DividerItemDecoration`. As soon as I got rid of that, it started to work. I suggest to put a line at the end of `xml` file for each item in `RecyclerView`, it's much easier to customize and you won't run into these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

No one of the previous solutions worked for me.

Finally I had to implement my own drawable for that, and its work like the provided by Android.

- Create a new drawable:

**res/drawable/selectable_item_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorAccent">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</ripple>
```

- Use it in you cell:

Just like you used the Android drawable

**android:background="@drawable/selectable_item_background"**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selectable_item_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    ...
```

For more info, or implementation for versions before API 21. Take a look to [this post](https://medium.com/@suragch/adding-a-ripple-effect-to-an-android-recyclerview-item-61249eb382b0).