# How to add a FloatingActionButton programatically

Tags: java, android, webview, floating-action-button

I'm trying to add a `FloatingActionButton` to my Android App whick has a WebView as the app content, but I can't figure out how.

Where and how should I go about it?

Thank you all in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    private WebView mWebview ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

        mWebview  = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.loadUrl("https://www.Camp-Ann.com/");

        setContentView(mWebview);

        FloatingActionButton reloadTab = getReloadFab(this);
    }

    public FloatingActionButton getReloadFab(Context context) {
        FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton(context);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mWebview.loadUrl( "javascript:window.location.reload( true )" );
            }
        });
        return fab;
    }
}
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634094/create-floatingactionbutton-programmatically-without-xml

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying *is* possible. But, according to the approach you are using, it is wrong.

1. So, first of all, you are not using binding so, we will use that.
2. You are not adding the fab to the view, so we will add that.

Now, to solve the problem, we will do both the things mentioned above with our final code looking like this:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    private WebView mWebview ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        mWebview  = new WebView(this);
   
        binding.getRoot().addView(mWebView);

        mWebview.loadUrl("https://www.Camp-Ann.com/");

        FloatingActionButton reloadTab = getReloadFab(this);

        binding.getRoot().addView(reloadTab);
        
    }

    public FloatingActionButton getReloadFab(Context context) {
        FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton(context);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mWebview.loadUrl( "javascript:window.location.reload( true )" );
            }
        });
        return fab;
    }
}
```